# Import 11GB PST file to Gmail without Outlook

Tags: gmail, import, pst, microsoft-office-2016, mbox

I was upgrading from Microsoft Office 2010 to 2016 last week and the installation failed, with error messages "Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016 encountered an error during setup" followed by "Microsoft bootstrap loader has stopped working" showing up.

Days of calling MS and following all their blog have failed me so far and now I have neither program installed on the computer, leaving me with only an exported 11GB PST file that I made just before beginning. It holds 15 years of contacts and emails that I need to reference every week and I can't wait anymore for MS to help with a fix for my installation.

As a short term fix I have installed Thunderbird, but their latest version doesn't import PST files anymore, so I need to import my large PST file into a Gmail account that I will setup and use for a while (or later export to an mbox file that I can import into Thunderbird).

1. Can Gmail directly import a 11GB file in a single shot without Outlook?
2. Is there a simple program that can convert a PST file to an mbox file without outlook?
3. Is there a simple pst reader that I can use to simply read my pst contact data and notes for a short time until I can get Office 2016 installed?

Comment: Question 2 and 3 is about software recomendation so you need to ask it on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ as it is off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 1):

G Suite Migration for Microsoft Outlook.

You can migrate email, contacts, and calendar data from Microsoft Outlook profiles and PST files to G Suite. Use this link to download G Suite Migration [tool](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/outlookmigration) and [**import PST file into Gmail account**](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/175943-how-to-import-pst-file-to-gmail-without-ms-outlook).

Comment: This wouldn't work for a free Gmail account though.

Comment: It looks like now you can import into free @gmail.com accounts.

Answer (score 1):

(ask the Word installation question...maybe some here would be able to help...)

I would recommend you to use the free software MailStore Home http://www.mailstore.com/en/mailstore-home-email-archiving.aspx

It can import (archive) from all kind of files/programs/services including PST files, and then it can export it to a whole range of programs/services including to a Gmail account or Thunderbird.

1. Download the program from [**their site**](http://www.mailstore.com/en/mailstore-home-email-archiving.aspx) and install it. (During installation you can, if you want, choose to do a portable installation in a directory instead of in the system.)
2. Open the program, click on **Archive E-mail** and in there on **Microsoft Outlook PST File.**[image]
3. Browse to the PST file, select it and press **Open** then **Next**. And complete the backup.
4. After backup presses is completed go to **My Archive**, right-click on this backup and go to **Export To** and select the place you want it exported to. (I would say exporting it straight to Thunderbird would be a better idea since it is all offline, and you aren't subjected to some problems Gmail sometimes makes for imports.)